# LINQ: search 2 properties for a list of strings

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a the following in varies parts of my code:

QuestionModel:

```
public class QuestionModel {
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

Keywords:

```
List<string> SearchKeywords
```

Questions:

```
List<QuestionModel> Questions
```

What I would like to achieve is from a list of ALL questions, to search and retain all questions that have ALL the keywords.

I'm gone as far as this but hit a road block:

```
var questions = GetAllQuestions(); //returns all questions as a List<QuestionModel>
Questions = questions.All(x => SearchKeywords.All(k => x.Question.Contains(k) || x.Answer.Contains(k)));
```

This however returns a bool.

Any help or directions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong LINQ method, you want [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx) instead of `All`:

```
Questions = questions.Where(x => ...);
```

`All` tells you if every item in the collection satisfies a condition (boolean result); `Where` filters the elements that satisfy the condition (filtered collection result).

Depending on what `Questions` is exactly (looks like a property, of what type?) you may have to wrap it up with `ToList` or `ToArray`.

Comment: First or Second all (I'm guessing first)

Comment: @GregB Take a moment to think about it before asking.  What does `All` logically do?  What does `Where` do?  What would it mean if you used `Where` for the first, and not the second?  What would it mean if you used `Where` for the second but not the first?  Don't just guess (even though you're compiler can answer the question for you in a few quick seconds by just trying it) you should understand what it would mean to do either, if you plan to actually learn how to use these methods.

Comment: @Servy Was thinking along that path, should have gave myself a few seconds to think it through. Always easier but not wiser to simply ask. Thanks for laying out for me though.

Answer (score 1):

The first [`All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) is wrong. You need [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx):

```
Questions = questions.Where(x => SearchKeywords.All(k => x.Question.Contains(k) || x.Answer.Contains(k))).ToList();
```

Also, as `Questions` is a `List<QuestionModel>`, you need `ToList`.